# Set primary key in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

The title is not entirely accurate, but I do not know how to explain, so I took a screenshot of where my problem is, and I will try to explain what I am trying to achieve.

I have a vehicle model, and when I create a new vehicle object, the name of vehicles just says `Vehicle object (1)` How can I change my model, or serializer (or something else) so that will show some unique value of the object.

[image]

Here is my model:

```py
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    make = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    license_plate = models.CharField(max_length=7, blank=True)
    vehicle_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    seats = models.IntegerField(default=4,
                                validators=[
                                    MaxValueValidator(70),
                                    MinValueValidator(4)],
                                )
    year = models.IntegerField(_('year'), default=datetime.today().year - 10, validators=[
                               MinValueValidator(1975), max_value_current_year])

    inspected = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    # fuel_type
    # fuel_price
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: Can you share your model.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem added

Comment: I guess overriding the `__repr__` method should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement a `__str__` method that returns a string, for example:

```
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    # …

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.make} ({self.year})'
```

You can thus return any string, and that will be presented by default in the Django admin and the drop downs.